# Select first row per run by group

Tags: r, duplicates, sequence, run-length-encoding

I have data with a grouping variable (ID) and some values (type):

```
ID <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3")
type <- c("1", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1")

dat <- data.frame(ID,type)
```

Within each ID, I want to delete the repeated number, not the unique one but the one the same as the previous one. I have annotated some examples:

```
#     ID type
#  1   1    1
#  2   1    3 # first value in a run of 3s within ID 1: keep 
#  3   1    3 # 2nd value: remove  
#  4   1    2
#  5   2    3
#  6   2    3
#  7   2    1
#  8   2    1
#  9   3    1
# 10   3    2 # first value in a run of 2s within ID 3: keep
# 11   3    2 # 2nd value: remove
# 12   3    1
```

For example, ID 3 have the sequence of values 1, 2, 2, 1. The third value is the same as the second value, so it should be deleted, to become 1,2,1

Thus, the desired output is:

```
data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"),
           type = c("1", "3", "2", "3", "1", "1", "2", "1"))

  ID type
1  1    1
2  1    3
3  1    2
4  2    3
5  2    1
6  3    1
7  3    2
8  3    1
```

I've tried

```
 df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

however what I got was

```
ID <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3")
type<- c("1", "3", "2", "3", "1", "1", "2")
```

I know duplicated would only keep the unique one. how can I get the values I want?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` `rleid` and `duplicated` -

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[!duplicated(rleid(ID, type))]

#   ID type
#1:  1    1
#2:  1    3
#3:  1    2
#4:  2    3
#5:  2    1
#6:  3    1
#7:  3    2
#8:  3    1
```

*Improved answer including suggestion from @Henrik.*

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(flag = case_when(type == lag(type) ~ TRUE, TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
     filter(!flag) %>% select(-flag)
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
  ID    type 
  <chr> <chr>
1 1     1    
2 1     3    
3 1     2    
4 2     3    
5 2     1    
6 3     1    
7 3     2    
8 3     1
```

Comment: Yes, it works :) I'm trying to learn the way you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Base R way If you want to eliminate consecutive duplicate rows only (8 rows output)

```r
ID <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3")
type<- c("1", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1")

dat <- data.frame(ID,type)

subset(dat, !duplicated(with(rle(paste(dat$ID, dat$type)), rep(seq_len(length(lengths)), lengths))))
#>    ID type
#> 1   1    1
#> 2   1    3
#> 4   1    2
#> 5   2    3
#> 7   2    1
#> 9   3    1
#> 10  3    2
#> 12  3    1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>